# Are there any solutions to make my ajax script stable regardless of HTML changing?

Tags: html, ajax, dynamic-content

I'm running a content-based website, and I usually used ajax to dynamically add items to the content list. Every time I updated my item structure I have to change my javascript to fit the new structure. I wonder whether there was any solution to keep script stable regardless of the changing of HTML?

Comment: It should be possible. But you need to post more details for us to help you. Please post your current code and let the people suggest you with what you want.

Comment: Upvotes for answers that help and accepting a final answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, instead of using the DOM to handle your data, process everything upon completion of the ajax request and only then call a function that has all of your data display functionality. Obviously you can't get away from having to change some code somewhere when you for instance rename HTML elements but you can separate concerns so that you only have to touch code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I do quite a bit of this in my app, and I follow the same pattern every time:

View page fires an ajax function to another page, which I call the "dispatcher"  I use this pattern because I want a plain text output without header, footer, other JS, etc, so the dispatcher is a simple page that gets the request from the Ajax, fires appropriate PHP functions, and echos the results.  In some cases it will return JSON strings while in others it will return HTML or plain text.  For your example, return HTML from your server-side language.

Back in the AJAX success callback, inner html (.html()) an element with the returned html content.  Have your server side language do the work of assembling the HTML (or even text if you're so inclined) because it is far less work and less overhead to accomplish.

Not too bad, huh?

Comment: That means the best way to handle this issue is that, let the server sid to handle all display pattern, is it?